# intersect usage on postgresql with row level security

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

```
create table user_table(
    idx text,
    _section text[]
);

create table section_table(
    _section text,
    sub_section text[]
);

alter table user_table enable row level security;

create policy user_p on user_table for select
using (section @> 
         (select _section from user_table 
            intersect
            (select _section::text[]
               from section_table 
               where current_setting('my.sub_section',true)::text[]
                     <@ (select sub_section 
                         from section_table)
            )
         )
      );

insert into user_table values
   (1,'{"section1"}'),(2,'{"section2"}'), 
   (2,'{"section2","section1"}');

insert into section_table values
   ('section1','{"s","b"}'), 
   ('section2','{"c","d"}');
```

expect output:

```
set my.sub_section ='{"c"}';
select * from user_table;
```

should only show `(2,'{"section2"}')`, but it shows everything.

When `sub_section` is entered, it should go to `section_table` and find the 
corresponding section and intersect with `user_table`, once the value of 
intersect is not null, then should return the corresponding value of 
`user_table`.

I am confused why it doesn't show the correct expect result.

Comment: Please format all your code, and don't format the rest of your text.

Comment: try to format the code, but there is no option to edit again T^T

Comment: thx Laurenz for helping me formating the code :)